# Dart Streams: get next value without duplication

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

I am trying to figure out a way to get subsequent values from Streams in Dart without duplication:

```dart
  // should resolve to first value received in stream
  Future f1 = mygetNextValueFn(stream); 
  // should resolve to second
  Future f2 = mygetNextValueFn(stream);
```

The idea here is for `f1` and `f2` to resolve to subsequent values in the stream, rather than to the same value. If I pull a value from `stream` as a future `f`, I want to make sure that the stream value that resolves `f` is unique to `f`.

I can do this using a wrapper class:

```dart
import "dart:async";
import "dart:collection";

class StreamWrapper<T> {
  Queue<Completer<T>> _completers;
  Queue<T> _values;

  _addValue(T value) {
    _values.add(value);
    _update();
  }

  _update() {
    while (_completers.isNotEmpty && _values.isNotEmpty) {
      Completer<T> completer = _completers.removeFirst();
      T value = _values.removeFirst();
      completer.complete(value);
    }
  }

  Future<T> next() {
    var complete = new Completer<T>();
    _completers.add(complete);
    _update();
    return complete.future;
  }

  StreamWrapper(Stream<T> stream) {
    this._completers = new Queue<Completer<T>>();
    this._values = new Queue<T>();

    stream.listen(_addValue);
  }
}
```

Then one can be assured the Futures from `streamWrapperInstance.next()` will always resolve to unique stream output values. This is kind of hackish, is there a more standard way to do this for a single subscriber stream?

Comment: Please add the implementation of mygetNextValueFn, if you have it.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you want to _pull_ from the stream, instead of the normal "stream pushes to me" ?

Comment: What about a transformer which only outputs a value if it differs from the previous one.?

Comment: I don't have an implementation of 'mygetNextValueFn', that's the part I am trying to figure out. I am not sure if pulling is the right term for what I am trying to do. A wrapper can be implemented for this, but I am wondering if there is a more standard way of doing this.

Comment: For me it's still not clear what you try to accomplish. Do you want two subsequent subscribers to not get the values the previous subscriber already received?

Comment: Precisely, I want to pull a future future from a stream, such that the value that the stream emits is reserved for that future exclusively. That means no one else can get that value except through that future. Remember, I am only concerned with single subscriber streams here.

Comment: Can't you just use a completer that completes when a value is returned? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

According to your new explanation this should fit your problem better:

```
import 'dart:async';

int _i = 0;

Future myGetNextValueFn(Stream s) {
  Completer c = new Completer();
  s.elementAt(_i++).then(c.complete);
  return c.future;
}

main() async {
  StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream stream = controller.stream;

  Future value1 = myGetNextValueFn(stream);
  Future value2 = myGetNextValueFn(stream);

  value1.then((val) => print('value1: $val'));
  value2.then((val) => print('value2: $val (1)'));
  value2.then((val) => print('value2: $val (2)'));

  controller.add('a');
  controller.add('b');
}
```

prints:

> value1: a
>   value2: b (1)
>   value2: b (2)

**OLD**

How about these two ideas:

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {
  StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream stream = controller.stream;

  // Idea 1
  stream.first.then((_) => print('1: $_'));
  stream.skip(1).first.then((_) => print('2: $_'));

  // Idea 2
  stream.elementAt(0).then((_) => print('1: $_'));
  stream.elementAt(1).then((_) => print('2: $_'));

  controller.add('a');
  controller.add('b');
}
```

prints:

> 1: a
>   1: a
>   2: b
>   2: b

Or if you want a solution using await/async:

```
import 'dart:async';

handler(Stream s) async {
  var x = await s.first;
  print('done for $x');
}

main() async {
  StreamController controller = new StreamController.broadcast();
  Stream stream = controller.stream;

  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    controller.add('a');
    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      controller.add('b');
    });
  });

  await handler(stream);
  await handler(stream);
}
```

prints:

> done for a
>   done for b
>   done

If you only have a single subscription stream use `stream.asBroadcastStream()` to get a broadcast stream!

Comment: I think you should move the edit to the top. It's quite a long answer and the edit seems to be quite a good answer to the question.